# How to get output on label from access batabas query

Tags: c#

How to get lable output from access database query?

```
con.Open();

  OleDbCommand cmdan = con.CreateCommand();

  cmdan.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

  string na = "SELECT top 1 Priimek_Ime from Dijaki ORDER BY rnd(ID_Dijaki)";

  cmdan.CommandText = na;

  OleDbDataReader n1 = cmdan.ExecuteReader();

  label2.Text = n1["Vprasanja"].ToString();

  n1.Close();

con.Close();
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. batabas == database? What is your exact problem?

Comment: i dont get output on label

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: this does not work label2.Text = n1["Vprasanja"].ToString();

Comment: You query "Priimek_Ime" but you do try to access the "Vprasanja" column. That would give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

You must read the OleDbDataReader

```
...
OleDbDataReader n1 = cmdan.ExecuteReader();
n1.Read();
label2.Text = n1["Priimek_Ime"].ToString();
....
```

Do note that Read() function does return a boolean with true if it did read. You could consider checking if you have data in your table.

```
if (n1.Read())
{
    label2.Text = n1["Vprasanja"].ToString();
}
else
{
    label2.Text = "No data found";
}
```

Comment: Check the edit, consider adding some feedback if your table has no data.